# Привязка поддоменов к портам на одном IP

Tags: proxy

Имеются foo.example.com и bar.example.com указывающие на один и тот же IP c открытыми портами 8080 и 8081 соответственно на которых крутится nginx.
Как сделать что бы при переходе например по foo.example.com открывался сервер на 8080 порту без редиректа?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name foo.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host      $http_host;
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }
}
```

и так:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name bar.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host      $http_host;
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8081;
    }
}
```

Надеюсь `8080` у вас абстрактный пример, т.к. прокси на SSL иные.